# jQuery clone row - insert value in specific field

Tags: php, jquery

Need some assistance here.

So basically I've got a form which has below fields. Once "Add More Products" button is clicked it clones the product, stock and qty fields and creates a new row. The Product field is a  dropdown list of products (query from mysql)

What I need help with is if someone chooses a product I need it to query the database and 
show stock levels on the chosen product. I've got it working with one row but can't get it to work on the cloned elements (respectively). Code is below. Would really appreciate some assistance.

```
<select name="product[]" id="product">
    <option value="product 1"> Product 1</option>
    <option value="product 2"> Product 2</option>
    <option value="product 3"> Product 3</option>
    <option value="product 4"> Product 4</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="stockclass="inputfield" name="stock" size="8" />


$('#product').on("change", function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("#stock").val(val2);                        
});

$("#add").on("click", function() {
    var row = $('#item tbody > tr:last').clone(true);            
    row.insertAfter('#itemsTable tbody > tr:last');
   return false;            
});
```

Comment: `live` is deprecated use `on` or `delegate`

Comment: also share html code..

Comment: @DipeshParmar HTML is in the code...

Comment: @devofash please have a look at my answer i have edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.on()` because `.live()` is depreciated from now on.

```
$(document).on('click','SELECTOR',function(){ /*...*/ });
```

You are cloning `DOMs` with the same `ID` that is totally wrong. Use `Class`.

**Example**

```
<select name="product[]" class="product">
    <option value="product 1"> Product 1</option>
    <option value="product 2"> Product 2</option>
    <option value="product 3"> Product 3</option>
    <option value="product 4"> Product 4</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="quantity inputfield" name="quantity[]" size="8" value="" />
<input type="text" class="target_price inputfield" name="target_price[]" size="8" value="" />
<input type="text" class="stock_availability inputfield" name="stock_availability[]" size="8" value="" readonly="readonly" />
```

Now other one is you have click event for selectbox that is wrong it should be change event.

**AS**

```
$('.product').on('change',function()
{

    $.ajax(
    {
        //ajax params and options and in success set value
    });

});
```

Comment: Changed  it all... still doesn't work... it puts the value in the first row of "Stock field" and not the respective cloned item

Comment: @devofash means your cloned DOM contain value inserted in parent DOM..?

Comment: Yup... that's correct. It shows the correct Stock Level but on the first row and not on the respective (2nd, 3rd, 4th etc) row.

Comment: @devofash you are already setting value to null after cloning...row.find(input select).val("") this is correct.

Comment: Yes, I have that because when "Add More" button is clicked it'll also clone the value in the Qty and Stock field and I obviously don't want that to happen...

Comment: @devofash sorry so what is the problem now.?

Comment: @devofash well thats why i told you to replace click event to change event...did you do that.???

Comment: Yes... I have. It still updates the stock level in the first row and not 2nd, 3rd etc row respectively.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25679/discussion-between-dipesh-parmar-and-devofash)